# How to increase and decrease the product count of each row of recycleview?

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

I want to increase and decrease the count of each row.
I did this but the problem is count value same for each row.so I want when user increase and decrease the count of row 0 the count 1
after that when user come to second-row count should start from 0 not be count 1
Please help me to resolve this issues??.I want to increase and decrease the count of each row.                                                   so According to count ,prize should be increased                                                               Row 1 Count 1,prize 100  =100                                                                                                 Row 2 Count 2,prize 200= 400                                                                                                                                                                                      But In my case count always showing last count value.for each row count value should be start from 1

Comment: so far what you tried?

Comment: Please, post the source code for better understanding the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried so far, but you can do something like this.

```
 holder.ivMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvItemQuantity.getText().toString());
            if (quantity > 0) {
                quantity = quantity - 1;
                storeItem.setItemQuantity("" + quantity);
                holder.tvItemQuantity.setText(storeItem.getItemQuantity());
                totoal = totoal * quantity;

           Gtotoal = Gtotoal - Integer.parseInt(storeItem.getItemPrice());
                ;
                settotal.setTotal(" \u20B9 " + Gtotoal);

            } else {

            }

        }
    });

    holder.ivPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvItemQuantity.getText().toString());
            quantity = quantity + 1;
            storeItem.setItemQuantity("" + quantity);
            holder.tvItemQuantity.setText(storeItem.getItemQuantity());

            Gtotoal = Gtotoal + Integer.parseInt(storeItem.getItemPrice());
            settotal.setTotal(" \u20B9 "+ Gtotoal);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.                                                                                       I want to increase and decrease the count of each row.

Comment: @SumitKumawat exactly i doing same